# Ошибка на Android API level 19

Tags: android

UPD: проблема решена при помощи способа, подсказанного anber и при помощи метода "наугад".
Я добавил фотографии в папку drawable-nodpi + удалил фон (background) ScroolVIew.

Крашится приложение в эмуляторе `Genymotion` только на `API 19`.

В чем может быть причина?

Вот log:

> 09-14 08:59:09.053    3011-3011/com.appcar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.appcar, PID: 3011
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.appcar/com.appcar.TwoActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
>               at com.appcar.TwoActivity.onCreate(TwoActivity.java:47)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
>               at com.appcar.TwoActivity.onCreate(TwoActivity.java:47)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
>               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>               at android.view.View.(View.java:3554)
>               at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
>               at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:119)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
>               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
>               at com.appcar.TwoActivity.onCreate(TwoActivity.java:47)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Как я понимаю, причина в "Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class ", но я и там не вижу ошибку!

Привожу содержимое xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/two_layout">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/car1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Car"
            android:id="@+id/two_layout_text "
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text2365"
            android:id="@+id/text_carsd"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Send2"
            android:background="@drawable/zero"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView46"
            android:textColor="#fffb0049"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Send2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Код Активити:

```
package com.appcar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import android.util.Log;


public class TwoActivity extends Activity {
Button SendLikes;
SharedPreferences preferences;
int LikeMade;
int LikesNumber;
int LikesPlus;
int LikesMinus;
TextView TextView46;
private static final String TAG = "TwoActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.twolayout);
```

Comment: Проблема не в разметке а в фрагменте. Опубликуйте его код

Comment: OutOfMemoryError словили

Comment: возможно `drawable/two_layout` или `drawable/car1` слишком большие.

Comment: как уже написали, приведенный код `TwoActivity` будет не лишним

Comment: Просто не могу понять, почему в Genymotion даже на самых слабых устройствах все ок, а только на API19 (независимо от мощности) - проблема.

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, добавил код.

Comment: @anber, да, скорее всего это `drawable/car1` так как `Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class` - это как раз этот ImageView

Comment: @user186295 форматирование кода пли3

Comment: @ermak0ff , я бы с удовольствием это сделал (самому глаза мозолит), только я не понимаю, как это сделать тут. Иногда все норм, а иногда нет. Я пользуюсь функцией "Пример кода", нужно как-то иначе его вставлять в сообщение?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29121/discussion-between-ermak0ff-and-user186295).

Comment: @ermak0ff , пока что не могу в чате: "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.". Но Вы правы: удалив строку android:background="@drawable/car1" , Активити запустилась. Как можно сделать так, чтобы фотография была на всех Активити? Весит она всего 845 КБ, не думаю, что это много.

Comment: @user186295 ну все и подтвердилось, ошибка в строке 47(TwoActivity.java:47) а 47 строка эт `setContentView(R.layout.twolayout);`

Comment: @user186295 сколько она весит это неважно. Какой размер в пикселях?

Comment: @anber , 759x769. Что следует сделать? Ужать, изменить размер, обрезать?

Answer (score 1):

Самое первое что следует попробовать в данной ситуации это переместить картинку на которой падает в папку `drawable-nodpi`. (Создать если такой нет).

UPD: Почему это обычно помогает: картинки из всех остальных каталогов автоматически масштабируются что приводит к избыточному потреблению памяти.

Comment: Могли бы объяснить, что это даст? Я к тому спрашиваю, что несколько дней промучился с выравниванием этой картинки по центру, чтобы она не растягивалась (параметр scyleType: centerInside). Если сейчас так сделать, как Вы посоветовали, картинка будет сохранять вышеупомянутый параметр или и из-за него в том числе падает?

Comment: @user186295 обновил ответ. Да, параметр `centerInside` сохранится. Вы для начала скажите удалось ли избавиться от OOME а потом будем разбираться с растягиванием картинки.

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ! Удалось загрузить второй layout, да. Только теперь картинка посередине экрана (отступы от правового края и левого примерно по 15% от экрана с каждой из сторон), то есть картинка не "fill_parent", как задано в настройках. Есть ли какой-либо способ разместить картинку по всей ширине экрана или хотя бы wrap_content?  Нужно ли добавлять другие фото и картинки из приложения в эту папку (есть несколько аналогичных layout по своей структуре)? В любом случае, благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @user186295 у вас в примере в ImageView высота ограничена android:layout_height="300dp", в этом проблема.  Попробуйте изучить этот документ и сделать как вам надо - http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2

Comment: я уже пробовал "играться" с этими настройками. А также изучал этот документ. Если сделать и высоту, и ширину "wrap_content" и добавить "scaleType:centerInside", я так и не могу добиться того, чтобы фотография расширялась.

Comment: @user186295 сделайте лучше отдельный вопрос на эту тему

Answer (score 1):

У вас в логе написано:

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Я бы для начала попробовал поменять картинку на более маленькую и посмотрел, что получается.