# Растянуть фотографию wrap_content при drawable-nodpi

Tags: android

Продолжение вот [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450703/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android-api-level-19/450727) вопроса.

Как растянуть фотографию на весь экран (или хотя бы wrap_content), чтобы было растянуто на всех версиях API и всех экранах? В частности не растягивается на API19.

Comment: Сколько в эмуляторе памяти указываете у устройства? Какое разрешение экрана? Размер изображения - 759x769?

Comment: Base Memory: 2048 MB, Размер изображения верно Вы указали, разрешение 1080x1920.

Comment: @lsillarionov , а с памятью это сильно связано? Я к тому, что даже на слабых устройствах (512MB) идёт на ура, а именно тут какие-то проблемы.

Comment: Боюсь что юзера @amber звать бесполезно, тут такого нет, есть только anber :) На сколько я видел у вас картинка лежит в ScrollView. Вы хотите чтобы она была по ширине на весь экран и по высоте пропорционально?

Comment: @anber , упс, пересидел за компьютером :) Да, Вы правы: в ScroolView есть картинка и текст. Нужно, чтобы картинка растягивалась либо fill_parent, а лучше - wrap_content. А по высоте занимала примерно 40-50% экрана. Все никак не могу понять, как это лучше сделать. Почти сделал с параметром "scaleType", но тут пошли проблемы с вылетами, о которых я спрашивал в предыдущем вопросе.

Comment: Вчера заметил, что, если зайти сначала во второй layout, потом на main, а потом на третий layout (и второй, и третий имеют полностью одинаковую структуру, только разница в контенте), то крашится на 3м layout и наоборот: если сначала зайти на 3й, потом на main, затем снова во второй - тогда крашится на втором. Возможно, следует очищать память после нажатия кнопки "Назад" (системная кнопка Андроид)?  Например, так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778754/kill-activity-on-back-button ? Как думаете, это должно помочь?

Comment: @user186295 поясните, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса, что значит "не растягивается на API19"?  Если вылетает с ошибкой, то добавьте трейс ошибки. Упростите свой пример из предыдущего вопроса до одного ImageView в FrameLayout (если так тоже получится воспроизвести)

Comment: Если вы хотите привлечь к решению вопроса конкретного участника, лучше дайте ссылку в каком-нибудь комментарии, используя его имя: `@anber ...`. В вопросе об этом писать не стоит, так как для сотен (или тысяч) будущих читателей это не имеет смысла.